# (maven) サブモジュール間の依存関係グラフを取得するには？

Tags: maven

mvn の、依存関係のグラフを出力したいと考えています。
その目的は、あるプロジェクトに含まれているすべてのサブモジュール間の依存関係を明らかにすることです。

これを実現するには、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

NOTE: mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot によって、各サブモジュール視点での、木構造的な dependency を graphviz 形式で出力できますが、ほしいのは、すべてのサブモジュール間の依存関係なので、自分のやりたいことが実現できていないと感じている状態です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ルートプロジェクトのディレクトリで下記のように[maven-graph-plugin](https://github.com/fusesource/mvnplugins/tree/master/maven-graph-plugin)を実行すると、モジュール間の依存関係を明らかにするグラフのPNGファイルが出てきます。

```
mvn org.fusesource.mvnplugins:maven-graph-plugin:reactor -Dhide-external=true
```

自分のテストプロジェクトでは、こんな感じでした：

[image: Dependency Graph for Test]